# Wired LWC in Service Console App does not React to Tab Switch/Focus

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, service-cloud-console

Service Cloud Console strikes again and is throwing me an interesting curveball. I have built an LWC Component that is wired to an Apex Method. The LWC is working, it's quite simple, and it has 2 states:

- "ready" shows a button that allows me to bump the LWC into "busy" mode
- "busy" shows a button that allows me to bump the LWC back into "ready" mode

The LWC wired method, on load, tells the LWC whether to render in "ready" or "busy" mode

The LWC is working well in standard navigation. Each time a page loads with the LWC on it, the wire method checks whether it should render as "ready" or "busy." If I interact with the LWC (set it from "ready" to "busy" or vice versa), the LWC refreshes instantly and shows the state change.

**Enter...** The Service Cloud Console App

Say I have 2 tabs open in the Console. The LWC is available on both tabs.

If the LWC is "ready", both console tabs show the LWC in "ready" state... this is desirable. The same would be true if it's "busy", both console tabs show "busy"... desirable.

**But if I interact with the LWC on either console tab... to bump it from "busy" to "ready" (or versa), the other console tab doesn't react and isn't aware of the change until I do a full refresh of the browser tab**

Can anyone point me towards documentation, pattern, or theory/concept on how I could have one tab's LWC be aware of the other tab's LWC change?

The end goal is that if one tab goes from "ready" to "busy" (or from "busy" to "ready"), the other tab(s) where the LWC is available should not still be in their previous state.

If necessary, although inefficient, I'd be ok if each console tab focus caused that tab's LWC to rewire (thus checking whether the state needed to be updated). For lack of a better description, it seems like the LWCs on each tab are caching.

**I have investigated the following, but they don't seem to address my challenge:**

- RefreshApex ([LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching))... Note:  I'm using RefreshApex in the LWC, which works great for the LWC/tab that is focused, but has no effect on other tabs' LWCs
- RefreshView ([LWC beta](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_refreshview_api) / [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation))
- Lightning:TabFocused ([Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabFocused/documentation))

Any suggestions here?

Thank you

Comment: How about [`notifyRecordUpdateAvailable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_notify_record_update)?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, 
So the wired value is actually a wrapper, it's not a record, really. I think, from other reading, that I'm going to need to rely on imperative apex here.

If it helps for context my "ready" or "busy" state is another way of saying "I'm working on this record"

The non-focused tab, when it comes back into focus, needs to understand that I've *now* indicated I'm working on the previously-focused tab.

As soon as I indicate "I'm working on something", I should have visibility on all tabs to the fact that I'm not "available to work on something"....... I'm busy!